# The order of features affects the results of a neural network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Well,
I am confused really.

I have a simple order of features, i.e. all the letters and a few symbols, counting how many times are contained in a string.

My selection as a result is as follows

```
numberOf_a
numberOf_b
...
numberOf_Z
numberOf_.
numberOf_,
```

I have a test sample of 65 values, and the MLP can get 46 correct.

Now If I chance the order of features in random order, train with the same data, evaluate the same values, I get a different number of correct predictions, e.g. 49.

Results are consistent (the same order will yield the same accuracy) but the accuracy changes between random orders.

The question is, is this supposed to happen? I cannot see how this is backed up by the theory. I am missing something large here?

PS. I am using WEKA's implementation of the MLP

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the WEKA implementation of the MLP but that doesn't seem like something that should be happening with a neural network algorithm.

It almost seems like it's getting stuck in some sort of local minimum.  The algorithm may be initializing the weights of the individual neurons the same way every time.  Changing the parameter order might then cause the algorithm to arrive at the same answer for a certain parameter order each time, dependent on the initial parameter order.  The "local minimum" might be determined by the algorithm only going through a certain number of iterations each time.